# A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute in android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm facing NotAuthorizedException in SignUp usign AWS cognito. Can anyone help me to fix this.

```
CognitoUserAttributes userAttributes = new CognitoUserAttributes();
userAttributes.addAttribute("FullName", fullName.getText().toString());
userPool.signUpInBackground(emailId.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(),          userAttributes, null, signUpHandler);
```

But, I'm facing below exception :
A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute `(Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: XXX-XXXX )`

Answer (score 5):

This error is due to the Cognito app client not having the write permissions for an attribute.

- In your Cognito userpool console, go to your userpool --> General settings--> App clients.
- Select the client being used and click on **Show details**
- Click on **Set attribute read & write permissions**
- Under writable attributes, select the required attributes and save. If you are not sure which attribute is causing the error try enabling them all & save

Comment: Wow, after creating a custom attribute you MUST go there and check each new field. Why in the world is that not default.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem but it was resolved by adding

Also make sure that in App Client -> Show Details -> Set attribute read and write permission.
Checked all custom attributes both side Read and Write.
And also in Client side code add 
custom: keyword as prefix in other attributes which are added as custom attributes.
While you are adding custom attributes
you need to add 
For example:

```
custom:full_name
```